# How can I figure out what to factor out?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, factoring

I can't wrap my head around this. Let's say I have this example

$256 + 765x + 864x^2 + 432x^3 + 81x^4 = 0$

Now I've already checked the solution which is $-\frac{4}{3}$. However I can't figure out what to factor where so that I get closer to a solution. During the solving steps you even have to write out a number as a sum of numbers to be able to factor it out. For example I should do

$256 + 765x + 864x^2 + 324x^3 + 108x^3 + 81x^4 = 0$

Where I split the $432x^3$ so that I could factor out $27x^3$ from $108x^3 + 81^4$ which would give me

$256 + 765x + 8624x^2 + 324x^3 + 27x^3(4+3x) = 0$

And factor out $(4+3x)$ in a similar manner from the rest. Now I can't look at the example and think "oh I can factor out $27x^3$ here easy peasy. Clearly I am not good enough with this type of problems. Would you be so kind and give me some general tips and how should I practice these?

Thank you

Comment: if you know how to perform long division of the polynomials, you can divide by $3x+4$

Comment: There's a problem: $-\frac43$ is *not* a root of that polynomial. It would be a root if the constant term was $252$.

Comment: The $765$ should be $768$, then the polynomial is $(3x+4)^4$.

Comment: Wolfram alpha shows [$\big(3x+4\big)^4$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%2881+x%5E4+%2B+432+x%5E3+%2B+864+x%5E2+%2B+768+x+%2B+256%29)

Comment: @poetasis No, $(3x+4)^4$ has coefficient $768$ before the $x$. The OP has a different polynomial (but most likely with a typo).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To summarise the comments, the most plausible answer is that the polynomial is indeed

$$
f=(3x+4)^4=81x^4 + 423x^3 + 864x^2 + 768x + 256.
$$

By the rational root theorem, one finds the linear factor $3x+4$.
Then, by long division, one obtains the quotient

$$
27x^3 + 108x^2 + 144x + 64.
$$

Again by the rational root theorem, there is a linear factor $3x+4$ with quotient
$$
9x^2+24x+16.
$$
And again once more!